# Mono and ASP.NET Web Application Connected to MS Access

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, ado.net, mono

I developed an ASP.NET web application that reads an MS Access database with ADO.NET.  This application will have to be run on Linux with Mono.  Unfortunately, I am having problems getting Mono to work with the ADO.NET database connection.

With the connection string enabled on an onLoad event, the web app will not render; however, when I delete the onLoad event, the web app renders in the browser.  I verified that it wasn't just the onLoad event as the problem by pressing a button that has an onClick event that reads the Access database, as well.  The problem then persists, which is the following error:  System.DllNotFoundException: gda-2...

I did some research on this error and downloaded the library libgda, but this did not fix the problem.  Now I am seeing posts that Mono doesn't work with MS Access driven ASP.NET web applications.

Has anyone been able to get an MS Access driven ASP.NET web Application to work with Mono?  If so, what steps did you take to get it to work?

I really appreciate everyones feedback, and if anyone has any suggestions, I would really be greatfull.

Thank you,

DFM

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that MS Access will work with mono, because it depends on the MS JET database engine which is not a part of the .NET framework itself, but a windows component.

That said, developing a web application that accesses an Access database is not a very good idea. Access is a desktop application, and not scalable for web application usage.

I would recommend that you find an alternative database engine, such as MySQL (since the application should run on Linux)

Comment: I agree. Developing a web application that uses Access and then trying to run it on Linux is just about as nightmare situation as I can think of. Don't do it!

Comment: well, even web applications running on Windows/IIS should avoid Access wherever possible, as I blogged here, http://blogs.msdn.com/lexli/archive/2009/06/26/database-for-web-applications.aspx